# Split a String into equal part in Java

Tags: java, split

I am having a very big string in html. I want to divide it into equal part in Java from `<span>` to `</span>`.

I am using the below regex but not getting the correct result:

```
<span class='ocrx_word'(.*?)<\/span>
```

Can anyone guide me. Thanks!

The String is:

```
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_1' title='bbox 577 190 656 222; x_wconf 72' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>ABC</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_2' title='bbox 671 190 854 232; x_wconf 69' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>Company</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_3' title='bbox 2011 190 2098 222; x_wconf 81' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>SHIP</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_4' title='bbox 2110 190 2177 222; x_wconf 84' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>TO:</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_5' title='bbox 2192 190 2261 222; x_wconf 69' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>XYZ</span> <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_6' title='bbox 2276 190 2461 232; x_wconf 70' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>Company</span> 
     </span>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using Jsoup for such things

Comment: I think your missing an opening span tag in your text. Either way your Regex gets 6 matches. What do you mean by splitting a String into equals parts?

Comment: split in equal parts means : Result like this :                                     <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_1' title='bbox 577 190 656 222; x_wconf 72' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>ABC</span>      <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_2' title='bbox 671 190 854 232; x_wconf 69' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>Company</span>

Answer (score 0):

Change the Regex like this:

```
<span\s*(class='ocrx_word'(.*?))<\/span>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: When I tried to use the above regex as suggested by use                           :<span\s*(class='ocrx_word'(.*?))<\/span>    . I m not getting the expected result.  can u tell me which tool are u using for the same.

Comment: @sumeetkumar Regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression

```
(<span class='ocrx_word'(.*?)<\/span>)
```

Comment: Not getting expected result: I want result like this from the string html           <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_1' title='bbox 577 190 656 222; x_wconf 72' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>ABC</span>                                             <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_2' title='bbox 671 190 854 232; x_wconf 69' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>Company</span>

Comment: May be it's not clear what you really want. I thought you want to split the html to and get each span tag separately. Is it not what you need?